# Using a date field in a ts?

Tags: r, time-series

I wonder how I can make use of an already existing date field when creating a ts in R. 
Sometimes you simply have a date before you have a ts object, e.g.

```
x <- as.Date("2008-01-01") + c(30,60,90,120,150)
# add some data to it    
df = data.frame(datefield=x,test=1:length(x))
```

Now, is there a way to use the datefield of the df to as an index when creating a ts object? Because:

```
   ts(df$test,start=c(2008,1,2),frequency=12)
```

(obviuously) completely ignores the date information I already have. Making use of ts methods like acf is the reason why I´d like to make it a ts object. I typcically use monthly an quarterly time series...

Comment: If its a regular time series, then why would you need to include the data information? If it isn't then you should use some other kind of time series object that handles irregular time series such as `zoo` or `xts`

Comment: @James: Good pointer. I haven't used time series objects to a point where I can tell xts, zoo or ts is best. Typically I just use none of them and prefer ggplot2 for plotting and use a lot of melt() – hence I can make use (note I am not sayin I need it) of a date column for labelling. Now I realize I'd like to use acf() and so on and I do not want to use one "time series object" for plotting and the other time series object for calculation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to create new types of objects from scratch; you can always coerce to other classes, including `ts` as you need to. `zoo` or `xts` are arguably to most useful and intuitive but there are others. Here is your example, cast as a zoo object, which we then coerce to class `ts` for use in `acf()`.

```
## create the data
x <- as.Date("2008-01-01") + c(30,60,90,120,150)
df = data.frame(datefield=x,test=1:length(x))

## load zoo
require(zoo)
## convert to a zoo object, with order given by the `datefield`
df.zoo <- with(df, zoo(test, order.by = x))
## or to a regular zoo object
df.zoo2 <- with(df, zooreg(test, order.by = x))
```

Now we can easily go to a `ts` object using the `as.ts()` method:

```
> as.ts(df.zoo)
Time Series:
Start = 13920 
End = 14040 
Frequency = 0.0333333333333333 
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> ## zooreg object:
> as.ts(df.zoo2)
Time Series:
Start = 13909 
End = 14029 
Frequency = 1 
  [1]  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [21] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [41] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [61]  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [81] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[101] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[121]  5
```

Notice the two ways in which the objects are represented (although we could have made the zooreg version the same as the standard zoo object by setting the `frequency` argument to `0.03333333`):

```
> as.ts(with(df, zooreg(test, order.by = datefield, 
+                       frequency = 0.033333333333333)))
Time Series:
Start = 13920.0000000001 
End = 14040.0000000001 
Frequency = 0.033333333333333 
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

We can use the zoo/zooreg object in `acf()` and it will get the correct lags (daily observations but every 30 days):

```
acf(df.zoo)
```

[image: acf figure]

Whether this is intuitive to you or not depends on how you view the time series. We can do the same thing in terms of a 30-day interval via:

```
acf(coredata(df.zoo))
```

where we use `coredata()` to extract the time series itself, ignoring the date information.

[image: acf figure 2]

Comment: Both answers really helped me to understand how this works – I only can accept one. I hand the extra points to Gavin because of the elaborate example with zoo / zooreg. Thx to Joris and James as well!

Comment: Note that you can just write `acf(z)` where z is a `"zoo"` series since `acf` converts it to a `"ts"` series internally anyways.  This will give the same result as `acf(as.ts(z))` .

Comment: @Gavin : you get the correct lags, which are the same ones as `acf(1:5)` for the simple reason acf() excludes all NA values. Only the X-axis will differ, and that's a matter of choice. I personally like the Lag indicated by the index, i.e. as integers starting from 1. This is in my opinion according to the definition of lag in arima, AR and CAR models. But it's a matter of taste, I agree on that one.

Comment: @Joris - indeed, and I make this point in my answer above; whether you consider the samples as units of 30-days or daily with a regular 30 days between each observation. I can see uses for both. Note that with the `zoo` object (not the `zooreg` one) there are no `NA` **and** it gets the lags "correct" for some definition of "correct" ;-)

Comment: @G. Grothendieck thanks for that point - makes the whole thing even simpler to use Zoo as the basis for storing the time series data.

Comment: @Gavin : ...for some definition of correct... I like that one :-) +1 btw for the conversions.

Comment: btw: `as.ts(with(...))` did not work for me with my real data (not the test here), I had to use `ts(with(...))` instead.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but acf also works on simple vectors, given off course it represents a regular time series (i.e. even spaced). Otherwise the result is just bollocks.

```
>acf(df$test)
```

[image]

Regarding the ts object :

The "dates" you see are just from the print.ts function, so they're not inherent to the ts object. The ts object has no date information in it. You can set the option `calender=FALSE` to get the standard print out of the ts object.

```
> ts(df$test,start=2008,frequency=12)
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May
2008   1   2   3   4   5
> print(ts(df$test,start=2008,frequency=12),calendar=F)
Time Series:
Start = c(2008, 1) 
End = c(2008, 5) 
Frequency = 12 
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Now, the vector you construct looks like :

```
> x
[1] "2008-01-31" "2008-03-01" "2008-03-31" "2008-04-30" "2008-05-30"
```

which is or isn't regular, depending on how you see it. If you extract the months, then you have 1 observation for january, 2 for march, 1 for april...: not regular. You have an observation every 30 days : regular. If you have an observation every 30 days, you shouldn't bother about the dates as 365 is not dividable through 30. Hence, one year you'll have 12 observations, another one you'll have 13 observations. So you can't set the frequency in ts in a consequent correct way.

So I'd refrain from using a ts all together, as James already indicated in the comments.

Comment: +1 @Joris you raise several interesting and useful points here

Comment: @Gavin : thx. I edited my answer to show how the lags are exactly the same, so no conversion is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want:

- Use the date information you already have
- Easily set the frequency to a desired value
- End up with a ts object

You can start with an xts object, add a frequency attribute, and then convert to ts:

```
library("xts")
my_xts <- xts(df$test, df$datefield)
attr(my_xts, 'frequency') <- 12  # Set the frequency
my_ts <- as.ts(my_xts)
```

The resulting ts object will have the specified period and will have the correct dates assigned to each data point.