# Can I make a time series work with date objects rather than integers?

Tags: r, date, time-series

I have time series data that I'm trying to analyse in R. It was provided as a CSV from excel, which I subsequently read as a data.frame `all`. Let's say it has two columns: `all$date` and `all$people`, representing the count of people on a particular date. The frequency is hence daily.

Being from Excel, the dates are integers representing the number of days since 1900-01-01.
I could read the data as `people = ts(all$people, start=c(all$date[1], 1), frequency=365);` but that gives a silly start value of almost 40000 because the data starts in 2006. The `start` parameter doesn't take a date object, according to `?ts`, so I can't just use `as.Date()`:

```
ts - ...
start: the time of the first observation. Either a single number 
or a vector of two integers, which specify a natural time unit and
a (1-based) number of samples into the time unit. See the examples 
for the use of the second form.
```

I could of course set `start=1`, but it's a bit painful to figure out what season we're in when the plot tells me interesting things are happening around day 2100. (To be clear, setting `frequency=365` does tell me what year we're in, but isn't useful more precise dates). Is there a useful way of expressing the date in `ts` in a human-readable form so that I don't have to keep calling `as.Date()` to understand when the interesting features are happening?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use `ts`, as opposed to, e.g., `zoo` or `xts`? (see also [this possible dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5182262/489704)).

Comment: when reading in the csv, specify the `stringsAsFactors` argument to be FALSE. Then use `as.Posixct` to convert date column to class `Posixct`. Read this http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/strptime.html for full list of date conversion functions.

Comment: (For example, if you just want to plot the data, then `all$date <- as.POSIXct(all$date * 24 * 60 * 60, origin="1900-01-01"); library(xts); plot(xts(all$people, all$date)); plot(zoo(all$people, all$date))`)

Comment: Thanks @jbaums, I wasn't aware of zoo and xts. It's much more flexible to work with these classes of objects than ts.

Comment: No problem, there are a couple of useful vignettes, listed [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html) and [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/index.html).