# Decimal date to date time using Lubridate for daily time series created by ts() in R

Tags: r, time-series

Here is the data:

```
dates  <- c("2014-01-02","2014-01-03","2014-01-04","2014-01-05","2014-01-06","2014-01-07","2014-01-08","2014-01-09","2014-01-10","2014-01-11","2014-01-12","2014-01-13","2014-01-14","2014-01-15","2014-01-16","2014-01-17","2014-01-18","2014-01-19","2014-01-20","2014-01-21")           
values <- c(0.53655983,-0.69226298,-0.35720551, 0.01142074,-0.69354153,-0.03032881, 0.84732451,-1.72182173, 0.96973604, 0.24409424,-0.05999542,-2.99607882, 0.34416389,-0.98285222,-0.54841516,-0.33842824,-0.32391938,-1.28737460, 0.30649339,-0.18067711)             
df     <- data.frame(Date = dates, Value = values)
```

I convert this into a daily time series, using the following lines:

```
library(lubridate)

start.date    <- decimal_date(ymd(df$Date[1]))
ts.main       <- ts(as.numeric(df$Value),
                    start = start.date,
                    frequency = 365)
```

Now if I look at the time stamps of the elements in the time series using time(ts.main) and convert it to datetime type using:

```
time(ts.main) %>% as.numeric() %>% date_decimal() %>% as_date()
```

I obtain:

```
[1] "2014-01-01" "2014-01-02" "2014-01-03" "2014-01-04" "2014-01-06" "2014-01-06" "2014-01-07" "2014-01-08" "2014-01-09" "2014-01-10" "2014-01-12"
[12] "2014-01-12" "2014-01-13" "2014-01-14" "2014-01-15" "2014-01-16" "2014-01-18" "2014-01-18" "2014-01-19" "2014-01-20"
```

which is not the correct time stamps. `2014-01-05` is missing while `"2014-01-06"` appears twice.

Either I am making a mistake in creating the time series or in converting the decimal time to date-time.

Kindly correct me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a possible alternative using the `xts` package:

```
require(xts)
xts.main <- xts(as.numeric(df$Value), order.by = as.Date(df$Date))
time(xts.main)
```

which gives:

```
 [1] "2014-01-02" "2014-01-03" "2014-01-04" "2014-01-05" "2014-01-06" "2014-01-07" "2014-01-08" "2014-01-09"
[9] "2014-01-10" "2014-01-11" "2014-01-12" "2014-01-13" "2014-01-14" "2014-01-15" "2014-01-16" "2014-01-17"
[17] "2014-01-18" "2014-01-19" "2014-01-20" "2014-01-21"
```

Comment: Thank for prompt response. `xts` solves the problem of time stamps but I can not use this object with functions form `forecast` package.

Comment: Hi! I've done some research and I've found that `ts()` doesn't handle very well date formats, maybe that's why you get that funny output. So I think that you need to use `as.ts()` before you use `forecast`, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182262/using-a-date-field-in-a-ts

Comment: I really appreciate your making effort to resolve. I tried as.ts() by this simply drops all date info and simply uses an index for time. So, `time(as.ts(xts.main))` simply returns 1,2,3....